# raspbian, react and lxsession autostart - node not launched

Tags: reactjs, raspbian, autostart

I have a nodejs app with react and express. I'm trying to get it to automatically start on boot on a raspberry pi (version 3 in this case) running raspbian.

The following autoscript works, in so far as I can see `node` processes.

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi                                                                                                                                                                                
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi                                                                                                                                                                      
@npm run server --prefix /home/pi/my-app
```

When I change `server` to `react`, ie. `@npm run react --prefix /home/pi/my-app` then when I do `ps -ef | grep node` I see nothing. However, the browser DOES launch but obviously can't find the site.

What am I missing? Which log file to check?

package.json excerpt

```
"scripts": {
 "react": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "server": "nodemon --inspect server/server.js",
 "all": "run-p server react",
 "debug_all": "run-p server react"
}
```

And for the record, it all runs fine on my PC.

Also, `npm run react`, on the pi, works but it doesn't launch a browser!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the error so instead...

- I built the site with `npm build`
- Changed `autostart` to call a new script
- The new script...

  - Launchs the server
  - Serves the react site
  - Launchs the browser